# titlesec errors out with res documentclass?

Tags: sectioning, templates, titlesec

```
\documentclass{res} 
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\begin{document}          
\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Argument of \section has an extra }.
```

error and few other errors.
Is there anything wrong with what I have, or will it just not work ?

I am running MiKTeX on windows 7

I am also wondering if there is a way to change the space after section without `titlesec` sense it's giving me this error

Answer (score 2):

The `res` class was written for LaTeX2.09 and only updated slightly for LaTeX2e. It uses it's own approach to sections, distinct from the LaTeX2e kernel and incompatible with anything that relies on 'LaTeX2e standards'. Given the age of the class, I'd suggest looking at alternatives.