# Using the titlesec package with the res document class

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, resume

I am trying to redefine the formatting of the my sections using the `titlesec` package within a `res` document. However, I am getting the following error message which only occurs if I try to run the minimalist document below in the `res` and not in the `article` class.

```
1466
! Argument of \section has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1466 \ttl@extract\section
```

Here is the minimalist document.

```
%\documentclass{article}

\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\center\sc\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
Lala

\end{document}
```

P.S. I know this question has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119915/titlesec-errors-out-with-res-documentclass) but there is has never been answered.

Comment: The `res` class uses its own method for defining `\section` which is incompatible with `titlesec`.

Comment: thanks. do you have any other solutions in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The `res` class uses its own method for defining `\section` and this can't work with `titlesec` that assumes the standard method.

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\def\section#1{%
  \ifx\\\@tabcr
    \@stopfield
  \else
    \@@par
  \fi
  \begingroup
  \everypar={}%
  \def\par{\@@par}\def\\{ }%
  \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
  \addvspace{\sectionskip}%
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\sectionfont #1\hss}%
  \addpenalty{-\@secpenalty}%
  \endgroup
  \ifx\\\@tabcr
    \@startline
  \else
    \vskip-\parskip\fi
 \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\sectionfont{\large\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
Lala\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Max Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.